# Time filter commands in django (timezone.now())

Tags: django

I'm brazilian, and i was reading a django tutorial, and find this, but i do not know what i'm seeing. Somebody could help me please?

what is more black than others it's what i'm not understand very well

> > Post.objects.filter(published_date**__lte**=**timezone.now()**)

i'm sorry if my english are wrong kkkkk

Thanks

Comment: the query set will return the POSTs which is posted earlier than current time. normally we using for getting old posts

Comment: lte = less than or equal. Timezones are different depending on where you are on earth. timezone.now() returns the datetime object for the given timezone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is filtering the object Post for all instances where the published date is less than or equal to the current time.